# Ubuntu: what does time command output means?

Tags: ubuntu, time

From running time over my program I've got:

```
real    4m41.679s
user    20m58.623s
sys 0m49.471s
```

What does this output means?
What is real and what is user?

Comment: To find this info on your local computer, run `info time` in a terminal (install docs first if it is not found). Look at the sections `Setting format` to see which variables the default output format uses and `Format string` to see what the variables mean. Also pay attention to that e.g. Bash uses its own built-in `time` command, and you have to invoke `/usr/bin/time` or similar (`see `which time` for the exact path, or just invoke `which time`) to run the "common" version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running `help time` in bash gives:

```
time: time [-p] pipeline
    Report time consumed by pipeline's execution.
    
    Execute PIPELINE and print a summary of the real time, user CPU time,
    and system CPU time spent executing PIPELINE when it terminates.
```

---

Running `man 7 time` give a description of `real`, `user CPU` and `system CPU` time:

> **Real time** is defined as time measured from some fixed point (e.g., the start) in the life of a process (elapsed time).
>
> **User CPU** time is the time spent executing code in user mode. **System CPU** time is the time spent by the kernel executing in system mode on behalf of the process (e.g., executing system calls).

Comment: Which of those is time elapsed from the beginning of the process till the end?

Comment: @Artem: As user1055604's answer (now) says: "Real" time means elapsed time for the command.